# X-axis visibility in the scatterChart model

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

How do I make the x-axis visible in a scatter Chart in NVD3? I have tried the following but it won't show up:

```
var chart;
nv.addGraph(function() {
chart.nv.models.scatterChart()
 .transitionDuration(300)
 .color(["blue", "green", "yellow"])
 .showXAxis(true)
 .showYAxis(true);
```

I've looked into the nvd3 source code but it looks like the scatterChart model has the x-axis set as visible through `showXAxis(true)` .  Is it a CSS issue? Please advise.

Thanks so much for your help.
Jorge

Comment: Could you give us a complete example that demonstrates the problem please?

Comment: I'm trying to show the vertical axis in this chart:  var chart;
    nv.addGraph(function() {
    chart = nv.models.multiBarHorizontalChart()
    .x(function(d) { return d.label })  
    .y(function(d) { return d.value })  
    .margin({top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 50, left: 175})  
    .showValues(false)  
    .tooltips(true)  
    .transitionDuration(500)  
    .stacked(true)  
    .showControls(true);  

    chart.yAxis.showMaxMin(false)
    .tickFormat(d3.format(',.0f'));  chart.xAxis.showMaxMin(false);

    d3.select('#chart1 svg').datum(long_short_data)
    .call(chart);

Comment: What's going on with the editing system?   I can't get it to format correctly!

Comment: Edit the question instead, that will allow you to format properly.